# Modularity and the most general $(p, q, r)$ case in the BeChDaYa paper.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

In the Bennet, Chen, Dahmen, Yazdani paper, [Generalized Fermat equations: A miscellany](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~ichen/pub/BeChDaYa.pdf), on page 24 in section 6 entitled "Future Work", they say:

"A limitation of the modular method at present is that the possible exponents
$(p, q, r)$ must relate to a moduli space of elliptic curves (or more generally, abelian varieties of $GL_2$-type). For general $(p, q, r)$, this is not the case."

Is there an example of a $(p,q,r)$ case where Darmon's program must fail?  General $(p,q,r)$ is the whole ballgame.  If all the conjectures that Darmon uses were proven, then what $(p,q,r)$ case remains that they might be referring to?  What $(p,q,r)$ use case do they have in mind?